# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a Spring Project with CRUD operation. I'm new to Spring, So I need a bit of help-

I'm getting a following error on submitting the form with post method-

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'userDao' of bean class
>   [com.cjc.service.RegistrationServiceImpl]: Bean property 'userDao' is
>   not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type
>   of the setter match the return type of the getter?    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>     ... 47 more
>
> Jan 23, 2019 9:01:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'userDao' of bean class
>   [com.cjc.service.RegistrationServiceImpl]: Bean property 'userDao' is
>   not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type
>   of the setter match the return type of the getter?    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)

Please find below the java files for the same-

Controller-

```
package com.cjc.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.cjc.model.User;
import com.cjc.service.RegistrationService;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Qualifier("regservice")
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    public void setRegistrationService(RegistrationService registrationService) {
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registration", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Registration(@ModelAttribute User u) {
        registrationService.addPerson(u);

        return "RegSuccess";
    }
}
```

Service-

```
package com.cjc.service;

import com.cjc.dao.UserDAO;
import com.cjc.model.User;

public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService {

    private UserDAO userDao ;

    public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }



    @Override
    public int addPerson(User u) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

}
```

DAO Impl-

```
package com.cjc.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.cjc.model.User;
import com.cjc.util.HibernateUtil;

public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDAO{

    @Override
    public void addUser(User u) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(u);

        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updteUser(User u, int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cjc.controller" />
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.cjc.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    </bean>
    <bean id="regservice" class="com.cjc.service.RegistrationServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDAO"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basenames" value="application" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: Can you show your getter method? The error message is very clear `Bean property 'userDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter`

Answer (score 0):

You missing setter and getter in User Model. Add setter and getter.

Comment: No Sir, I already have setter getter in my **User.java** (pojo class)

Comment: Try add 
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao ; in your service

Answer (score 0):

Add getter in RegistrationServiceImpl class for UserDao:

```
public UserDAO getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}
```

Comment: I added getter method as well but still same issue